# updating data in edit-form react

Tags: reactjs

I have a kind of todo, but there are several lines in one object.

I need that when editing one of the fields and pressing the save button, the save will work.

Now, in order to save the changes, need to change all three inputs.

[Here is my code in stakeblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jb6td5)

**App.js**

```
function App(props) {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(props.tasks);
  function editTask(id, newName, newTranslate, newNote) {
    const editedTaskList = tasks.map((task) => {
      if (id === task.id) {
        return { ...task, name: newName, translate: newTranslate, note: newNote };
      }
      return task;
    });
    setTasks(editedTaskList);
  }

  const taskList = tasks
    .map((task) => (
      <Todo
        id={task.id}
        name={task.name}
        translate={task.translate}
        note={task.note}
        completed={task.completed}
        key={task.id}
        editTask={editTask}
      />
    ));

  return (
    <div className="todoapp stack-large">
      <ul
        className="todo-list stack-large stack-exception"
        aria-labelledby="list-heading">
        {taskList}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I thought that the problem was with the handlers in the todo file, most likely there need to get the previous data from the state, and if the field has not been changed, then use this data as changed in the new state. I tried to do something like this but I couldn't find anything.

**Todo.js**

```
export default function Todo(props) {
  const [isEditing, setEditing] = useState(false);
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState('');
  const [newTranslate, setNewTranslate] = useState('');
  const [newNote, setNewNote] = useState('');

  function handleChange(e) {
    setNewName(e.target.value);
  }
  function handleChangeTranslate(e) {
    setNewTranslate(e.target.value);
  }
  function handleChangeNote(e) {
    setNewNote(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!newName.trim()|| !newTranslate.trim() || !newNote.trim()) {
      return;
    }
    props.editTask(props.id, newName, newTranslate, newNote);
    setNewName("");
    setNewTranslate("");
    setNewNote("");
    setEditing(false);
  }

  const editingTemplate = (
    <form className="stack-small" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label className="todo-label" htmlFor={props.id}>
          New name for {props.name}
        </label>
        <input
          id={props.id}
          className="todo-text"
          type="text"
          value={newName || props.name}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input
          id={props.id}
          className="todo-text"
          type="text"
          value={newTranslate || props.translate}
          onChange={handleChangeTranslate}
        />
        <input
          id={props.id}
          className="todo-text"
          type="text"
          value={newNote || props.note}
          onChange={handleChangeNote}
        />
        
      </div>
      <div className="btn-group">

        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn todo-cancel"
          onClick={() => setEditing(false)}
        >
          Cancel
        </button>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn__primary todo-edit">
          Save
          
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );

  const viewTemplate = (
    <div className="stack-small">
      <div className="c-cb">
          
          <label className="todo-label" htmlFor={props.id}>
            {props.name}
          </label>
          <label className="todo-label" htmlFor={props.id}>
            {props.translate}
          </label>
          <label className="todo-label" htmlFor={props.id}>
            {props.note}
          </label>
          
        </div>
        <div className="btn-group">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn"
          onClick={() => setEditing(true)}
          >
            Edit <span className="visually-hidden">{props.name}</span>
          </button>
        
        </div>
    </div>
  );
  return <li className="todo">{isEditing ? editingTemplate : viewTemplate}</li>;
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: I want to be able to save the form when changing one or two fields.Now can save only by changing three fields

Comment: I am able to save fields individually. Can you elaborate on your query

Comment: when I need to change the first field and the others don't, I can't save it, the save button doesn't work, need to change three fields for save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By many attempts and errors, I found how to solve my problem.

It's necessary to transfer data from the array to the new state, which will be the initial data for it

**Todo.js file**

```
export default function Todo({name, translate, note, editTask, id}) {
  const [isEditing, setEditing] = useState(false);
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState(name);
  const [newTranslate, setNewTranslate] = useState(translate);
  const [newNote, setNewNote] = useState(note);
```